# PyCharm 2016.3 настройки pep8

Tags: pycharm

В последней версии Pycharm пропала подсветка некоторых предупреждений, а именно - когда между классами меньше двух строк - волнистой линией подсвечивалось что это не совсем хорошо, так же появлялось предупреждение, если строка содержала более 120 символов. 
Уже привык к этому и никак не могу понять как это включить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Включил все галочки, но результата нету.

- Между классами меньше двух строк,
- Строка более 120 символов
- Файл должен заканчиваться пустой строкой
  Ничего из вышеперечисленного не подсвечивается.

Повторюсь что это именно в последнем PyCharm 2016.3 на Mac os X

Answer (score 1):

File -> Settings (PEP 8 внизу справа):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вот в том то и дело что не помогает.. Включил все галочки, кроме одной (та что выводит уведомление что метод может быть статичным).

Comment: @wedoca, Только что обновился до `2016.3` и всё нормально работает. Попробуйте переименовать/удалить папку `.idea` в корне проекта.

Comment: @wedoca, тут, вроде, похожая проблема: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17139485/how-to-get-pycharm-to-check-pep8-code-style

Comment: Создал новый проект, проблема повторилась. Удалил папку .idea и снова открыл новый проект - ничего не изменилось. Наверно это просто баг, так что будем ждать обновлений. Спасибо за отклик.

Comment: @wedoca, обновления дождались? :)

Comment: @gil9red, Возможно. На моем маке поменялся диск на ssd, на новой Os, как и на других компах проблема больше не появлялась.